# react, state updated but not render

Tags: reactjs, state

I allow myself to post this publication because I have not been able to solve this problem for a week now. I managed to find alternatives but not good in my opinion.

Here, I am developing an application in react to create contests.

So, in the application I have a "contest" object which stores a lot of information. This is stored in a state but when I change a value in the object it does not refresh the content.

Therefore I have to be forced to use the forceUpdate() function to force the refresh.
I also used useEffect with the state contest variable but nothing helped.

codes:

```
const [ignored, forceUpdate] = useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);

const { course, contest } = useContext(ContestContext);
const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);

const addTeam = (team) => {
    const teams = [...contest.teams, team];

    contest.teamsInc++;
    contest.teams = teams;

    setTeams(teams);

    ContestHandler.updateContest(contest);
}

const removeTeam = async (team) => {
    const teams = contest.teams.filter((team_) => {
        return team_.id !== team.id;
    });
    contest.teams = teams;
    setTeams(teams);

    ContestHandler.updateContest(contest);
}

if (contest.teams == undefined) {
    contest.teamsInc = 0;
    contest.teams = [];
    ContestHandler.updateContest(contest);
}

const start = () => {
    course.start();
    forceUpdate();
}

const stop = () => {
    course.stop();
    forceUpdate();
}
```

a class from where I apply modifications:

```
export default class CourseThreePart extends Course {

constructor(contest){
    super(contest);
}

start(){
    if(this.canStart() && this.draw()){
        this.state.contest.started = true;
        this.state.contest.status = ContestHandler.STATUS_IN_PROGESS;
        //ContestHandler.updateContest(this.state.contest);
        return true;
    }
    this.clearAlerts();
    this.state.alerts = [...this.state.alerts, 
        {
        level: "danger", 
        message: "L'application ne parvient pas à lancer le concours de pétanque."
        }
    ]
    return false;
}

draw(){
    let teams = [...this.state.contest.teams];
    const freeWin = teams.length % 2;
    const parties_length = (teams.length / 2) + (freeWin ? -1 : 0);
    let parties = []

    const randomTeam = () => {
        const team = teams[Tools.random(0, teams.length - 1)];
        teams = teams.filter((team_) => {return team_.id !== team.id});
        return team;
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < parties_length; i++){
        const firstTeam = randomTeam();
        const secondTeam = randomTeam();

        const index = i;

        parties = [...parties, {
            id: index, 
            status: ContestHandler.PARTY_IN_PROGRESS, 
            firstTeam: firstTeam,
            secondTeam: secondTeam,
        }]
    }

    if(freeWin) {
        /**
         * Créer la free win
         */  
    }

    if(this.state.contest.rounds == undefined){
        this.state.contest.rounds = [];
    }
    this.state.contest.rounds = [...this.state.contest.rounds, {id: this.state.contest.rounds.length+ 1, parties: parties}];
    console.log(this.state.contest);

    return true;
}

canStart(){
    return this.state.contest.teams.length >= 8;
}

getAlerts(){
    let alerts = this.state.alerts;

    if(this.state.contest.teams.length < 8){
        alerts = [...alerts, {
            level: "danger",
            message: "Vous devez avoir minimum 8 équipes afin de lancer le concours."
        }]
    }
    if(this.canStart() && this.state.contest.teams.length % 2){
        alerts = [...alerts, {
            level: "warning",
            message: "Attention, vous aurez une équipe qui sera tirée au sac étant donné que vous n'avez pas un nombre d'équipe paire."
        }]
    }

    return alerts;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Stop changing the state directly. For this you have this.setState method which is supposed to be used when updating state. When you edit object or array directly like obj.prop = value, or arr[index] = value, you don't change the object itself so it's not being treated like a change, that's why the component is not being rerendered.

React in case of non-prymitive state fields sees change only when its reference is chaning.

Comment: I take notes of your information which can help me for other components which will be displayed on the screen.

But in my case, the object that I update is a simple class, I don't use the rendering of this one, it just allows to store data and to have functions like start(), stop( ) , canStart() and others.